# How do you tweak "-webkit-" prefixed CSS properties in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(this).css({
    -webkit-transform:'rotate(180deg)',
    -moz-transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
    -o-transform: 'rotate(180deg)',
    -ms-transform: 'rotate(180deg)'
});
```

This is throwing the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

I'm really hoping I don't have to install the jQuery Rotation plugin just for this one instance.

Comment: if you ever get tired of writing those prefixes in your stylesheets, then check this out http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
$(this).css({
    '-webkit-transform':'rotate(180deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
});
```

Answer (score 80):

Quote them:

```
$(this).css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-moz-transform':    'rotate(180deg)',
    '-o-transform':      'rotate(180deg)',
    '-ms-transform':     'rotate(180deg)'
});
```

Answer (score 25):

Just a little addition to the current answers: If you use jQuery 1.8 you don't have to add the prefixes yourself. jQuery will automatically add the appropriate prefix for you.

That means that this code will be enough:

```
​$(this).css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You won't have to worry about adding new prefixes or removing them if the browser adapted the unprefixed property. :)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/72NHs/1/)'s a live demo. If you visit the page with a WebKit Browser and inspect the body, you can see that jQuery added `-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);` as a style.

Take a look at the *Automatic CSS prefixing* section here: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Answer (score 11):

Just to add a little more variety to the list of answers, you can also do

```
$(this).css({
    WebkitTransform: 'rotate(180deg)',
    MozTransform:    'rotate(180deg)',
    OTransform:      'rotate(180deg)',
    msTransform:     'rotate(180deg)',
    transform:       'rotate(180deg)'
});
```

Dashes in CSS property names are converted to camelCase in JS for compatibility., so when you use '-webkit-transform' (as in the above examples), jQuery just converts that to WebkitTransform internally.

Answer (score 2):

The new hip way to format commas:

```
$(this).css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
    , '-moz-transform':    'rotate(180deg)'
    , '-o-transform':      'rotate(180deg)'
    , '-ms-transform':     'rotate(180deg)'
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason for this? It seems silly, but then most hipster things do :)

Comment: I like this formatting, as it allows you to cut and paste lines of code without having to add or remove commas from the previous line.

Comment: Except for the first line, whereas the standard formatting lets you cut and paste without adding or removing commas... except for the last line. If it ain't broke...

Comment: Fair enough. I see now that the traditional formatting is superior, since the first line and any other lines aside from the last would be interchangeable.

Comment: Leading commas is less error prone and easier to manage because most the work happens at the bottom of the stack. Once you get this `//commenting a line out` is easier, cutting and pasting is easier and seeing the leading comma will help avoid errors by making them more obvious.

Comment: I thought comma-first was great for a while, but now realize that it's sort of pointless (in javascript), since [trailing commas are ignored](http://www.2ality.com/2013/07/trailing-commas.html). Using a trailing comma on every line also makes git diffs nicer (since you can just a remove a line and ignore whether the line above it still needs a comma).

Comment: Trailing commas break IE