# Upper camel case vs. lower camel case in vendor prefixes

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, vendor-prefix

The following both seem to be working:

```
element.style.WebkitFlex = 1;
element.style.webkitFlex = 1;
```

But which syntax is standard?

Answer (score 1):

The first,

```
element.style.WebkitFlex = 1;
```

is the preferred syntax. To [reference vendor-prefixed CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935821/4608094) inside of JavaScript while using the non-normalized, exact CSS property name, we must rely on the use of bracket notation:

```
element.style['-webkit-flex'] = 1;
```

This is, unfortunately, rather unwieldy. Dot notation affords itself better for these situations, and it is in that spirit why we also have the ability to reference vendor-prefixed properties using their camelCased counterparts.

In the process of normalizing property names between CSS and JavaScript, dashes are recognized as a delimiter. They are, obviously, parsed out altogether in the resultant camelCased property name but, nevertheless, are taken into account. In particular, the (delimiting) dashes signal where to apply different casing (*i.e.*, the Uppercased lettering). And, even though they are not alphabetical characters, a dash occupies the first position in (most) vendor-prefixed CSS properties, meaning the specific vendor's name prefix becomes capitalized. This procedure is also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9438962/4608094).

Thus, `element.style['-webkit-flex'] = 1;` becomes

```
element.style.WebkitFlex = 1;
```

Similar rules apply to the other vendors, such that we could also have...

```
element.style.MozTransition = 'width 1s 0s ease-in-out';

element.style.OTransform = 'scaleX(1.5)';
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066941/4608094) explains, this normalization procedure is applied under the hood in certain libraries including [jQuery](https://jquery.org/), among others.

Further evidence of this kind of procedure can be seen in other parts of the spec. For example, the [HTML5 `dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) defines [similar rules](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-dataset) for how to parse data-attributes.

Comment: I will emphasize what you said cause it threw me for a loop: "**...this normalization procedure is applied under the hood in certain libraries including jQuery, among others.**" I had never seen or heard of that before. Note that this question is 3 years old.

Comment: @Rob String manipulation is timeless. Here's one instance of this kind of normalization, albeit with the `-ms-*` vendor prefix in this case. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/731c501155ef139f53029c0e58409b80f0af3a0c/src/core.js#L41

Comment: Yes but the question was tagged javascript and that stuff is jQuery which I couldn't even find anywhere by Googling.

Answer (score -1):

As this is related with style property we should use established camel case notation that gets used with CSS properties.

All style related properties are named like below:

**font-variant
line-height
letter-spacing
word-spacing
text-align**

So we should stay with established practice.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Hermes - I am assuming you are looking for best practices of naming conventions.