# Why are jquery .css transition edits not being applied in safari, but .css transform edits are?

Tags: jquery, safari, css-transitions

I'm trying to use jquery to edit the css of an element to give it a random transition time, then rotate the element.

This all works fine in chrome, but in safari the first line of css edits aren't made, so all the transitions occur at the predefined speed.

```
 var rspeed = (Math.random()/3)+0.6,
    rtext = 'transform ' + rj + 's ease-in-out';

$('#tile').css( '-webkit-transition',rtext).css( '-moz-transition',rtext).css( '-ms-transition',rtext).css( '-o-transition',rtext).css( 'transition',rtext);
$('#tile').css( 'transform','rotateY(180deg)');
```

Why aren't the first edits being applied in safari?

EDIT:
Here's an example to try in safari that highlights the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ianbutterworth/5fnSF/30/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935815/how-do-you-tweak-webkit-prefixed-css-properties-in-jquery

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't a duplicate. I've added a jsfiddle example to highlight the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, by changing the settings for 'all' transitions, rather than just 'transform'. The problem was that 'transform' needed -webkit- etc. prefixes. Adding 'all' is the shortest option

```
var rspeed = (Math.random()/3)+0.6,
    rtext = 'all ' + rj + 's ease-in-out';

$('#tile').css({'transition':rtext,'transform':'rotateY(180deg)'});
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery css edit the style attr of your element and not your CSS files. So each time you call .css() you override yours last changes.

When you have multiples rules use:

.css({ "-webkit-transition": rtext, "-moz-transition": rtext, ..., "transform": "rotateY(180deg)" })

to not override yours lasts rules.

Comment: thanks. I appreciate that your answer is correct logically, but unfortunately it's not solved the issue. The rotateY css change is applied but not the transition settings still

Comment: This jsfiddle highlights my issue. Try this in Safari vs other browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/ianbutterworth/5fnSF/27/

Comment: (Note that I'm not using prefixing here because jquery is handling that automatically, but the issue remains when prefixing explicitly)