# Turn off -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator for certain inputs?

Tags: jquery, webkit

I turned on the webkit-calendar-picker-indicator for all inputs all the time with:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    opacity: 100;
}
```

This is good, and shows the user that there are drop-down choices in various input fields.

However, there is a table of inputs on a sales order form that I
would like to turn off the down arrow, so I tried the code below from this SO post: [How do you tweak "-webkit-" prefixed CSS properties in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935815/how-do-you-tweak-webkit-prefixed-css-properties-in-jquery)

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#Item'); 
$('items[row]').css({ '-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator':'display(none)' });
```

Where [row] is an index 0,1,2,3 etc for sales form Item "inputs" fields.

But sadly, that doesn't work.
Is this even possible?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I was over thinking it. I fixed it.
After setting all input types to opacity:100 to turn em on permanently, Use the Id (Item) of the element for which I wanted default webkit-calendar-picker-indicator behavior (show on-hover only) thusly:

```
#Item::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    opacity:0;
}
#Item:hover::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
   opacity:100; 
}
```

That did the trick.